# Resized macOS Partition in Windows; boots to white screen

Tags: bootcamp, recovery, dual-boot

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro and I am using Windows on Bootcamp and I tried installing Phoenix OS. Used a partition app on Windows and shrank the macOS partition.

Now whenever I start white screen shows up and recovery does not work. I’ve tried everything but it doesn't boot past that white screen. If I keep just R pressed Windows will boot up normally. Please help. Holding Alt doesnt work either

Comment: Which partition app would that be? Which version of Windows? Do you know Windows is installed to BIOS or EFI boot?

Comment: Have you tried internet recovery (`Cmd-Opt-R`)?  Do you have a backup?  What version of macOS?  What partition utility?

Comment: I dont have backup. I tried internet recovery too. It is not showing up. I mistakenly tried to shrink macos partition on windows. May have messed up the encryption of macos partition. I tried everything including safe mode and recovery mode. Nothing is working. Cant open anything. Not even windows

Comment: Windows 10. Partition utility I dont know. dios or efi i dont know

Comment: Latest MacOS. Update a week earlier.